# Way to export a snippet of view from a module in Nodejs10.x/expressjs 4.16.x/EJS 2.6.x?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Is there a way in `nodejs/expressjs/ejs` module to export a snippet of view code? I would like to build a log module which logs message for various models in my project. I just need to popup a small screen with text field for user to enter the log message.

I know `module.exports` can export functions from a module. What can I use to export a view code of a popup screen taking input from user?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about. You can export a string. Is this what you need?

Comment: I need to export a html page with text box to take user message. Not sure if this can be done with module.exports. thanks.

Comment: Like `module.exports = \`<html>...\``? Then do that. Is there a need to use a module? This could be text file, like it's usually done for templates.

Comment: Need to present the html text input whenever there is need for log message input.

Comment: That this possibly XY problem that can be solved with EJS partials stored as template files. Consider reasking the question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that reflects your case.